# JavaScript variable reference problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, reference

I'm trying to send a request and then in callback function, change the parameters and then send the request again. Something like this:

```
function sendRequest() {
    params = {param1:'value', param2:'value'};
    while(params) {
        $.getJSON("url", params, function(data) {
            if(data contains something important)
                params.foo = bar;
            else
                params = null;
        });
    }
}
```

But `params` never changes and the `while` loop continues for ever. It seems to be a reference problem; but I can't figure out how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `getJSON` is asynchronous.

1. `while(params)` executes. It's truthy, so we continue
2. `$.getJSON` is called. The function passed to it will not be called at this time. It's just queued to the subsystem that later will perform the actual request - asynchronously.
3. `while(params)` executes again. The callback passed to `getJSON` has not gotten a chance to run yet, so `params` is unchanged.
4. Go to step 2.

In other words, you created an infinite loop, since the system that processes the queued callback function never gets to execute because of the infinite loop. All you end up doing is creating a infinitely long list of queued `getJSON` calls.

A better solution would be something like this:

```
function sendRequest(params) {
    $.getJSON("url", params, function(data) {
        if(data contains something important)
            params.foo = bar;
            sendRequest(params);
        else
            params = null;
            // Probably do something like requestChainFinished(params);
    });
}

sendRequest({param1:'value', param2:'value'});
```

By using a function, you take control of the flow and don't perform another request until the asynchronous callback to `getJSON` has been called.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. I just didn't notice that it is async.

Comment: Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, make sure you tag one of the answers to your questions as answered by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

'params' is a closure variable. The value of params changes at a later time in the callback when the asynchronous ajax call's response arrives, but your while loop is keeping the JS engine busy that the callback isn't going to get called ever.

Either you could keep calling the same function in the response callback or you can use `async: false` like this `$.ajax({ async: false, ...`